# Stream Screen-Content over Network to DLNA TV

Tags: macos, video, streaming, video-streaming, dlna

So i got this new TV that is DLNA compliant and can play video files and streams from the network. This works great already with files from a streaming server (Windows Server running Serviio) inside the network setup.

But now i'm trying to stream my screen from my Mac to my TV as there is video content I can not directly play back on the TV. In this specific case it is video content from a video on demand service only providing a stream to silverlight web players.

Any suggestions on a software that is able to capture my screen would be greatly appreciated.

Some basic things the software should be capable of:

- Runs on Mac OS X Lion
- It should be configurable which of the screens from my dual-head should be captured
- Provide an (mp4/mpeg + mp3/aac/ac3) stream over http from that capture
- Low latency/delay preferred, there's nothing wrong with 10 seconds buffering or something like that but it shouldn't take 5 minutes of delay (let's say i want to fast forward a few minutes, it should be somewhat usable)
- (Optional +1) It would be perfect if the software can create a 3rd virtual monitor for the video, so you can work on the Mac in parallel)
- (Optional +1) Free (as in beer)
- (Optional +10) OpenSource

Comment: Did you solve this in real life?

Comment: No, not until now :(

Comment: Apple TV on newer macs (>2011) seems to do AirPlay quite well. For my older iMac  found airparrot work ok for screen and beamer work Great for movies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it if you are on Linux. Perhaps a similar setup will work on OS/X.

http://realmike.org/blog/2011/02/09/live-desktop-streaming-via-dlna-on-gnulinux/

The correct solution to this problem though, would be WirelessHD as seen here: http://www.anandtech.com/show/2912

Comment: Yeah i tinkered with a solution like that already using VLC as a transcoder between the screen and stream but it's not really an optimal solution. The stream tends to break after a while.

Comment: Well since this is somewhat helpful and with a great distance the best answer i'll award you the bounty :)